# WPF Binding to properties of an object with specific attributes

Tags: wpf, reflection, binding

I have a listbox to which I have bound the data context to an object. This object has a number of properties some of which will have a particular attribute.

What I want to do from this is to have the items source set to the properties of the object but to only display those properties that have a particular attribute set.

Can anyone help with where I would start on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ and reflection to get the values of the properties which have that attribute set:

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1 { Name = "Sam", DOB = DateTime.Now, SSN = "123" };

MyListBox.ItemsSource = from p in typeof(Class1).GetProperties()
                        where p.IsDefined(typeof(Att), false)
                        select p.GetValue(class1, null);
```

Name and DOB are marked as [Att] in my test, and their values are added to the ListBox. SSN is not.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to build your data context [object dynamically](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/binding-dynamic-properties/) and bind the Visibility properties to properties on this dynamically built object.  You would then use it in the following way:

```
var provider = new MyDynamicProvider();
// Add the names of the properties with the particular attribute with 
// initial values (found using reflection elsewhere). 
provider.MyValues.Add("PropertyWithAttribute", "Test");
provider.MyValues.Add("PropertyWithAttributeVisibility", Visibility.Visible);
// Add properties that do not have the attribute
provider.MyValues.Add("PropertyWithoutAttributeVisibility", Visibility.Collapsed);
view.DataContext = provider.CreateDynamicWrapper();
```

In the view you can now do the following:

```
<TextBlock 
    Visibility="{Binding PropertyWithAttributeVisibility}" 
    Text="{Binding PropertyWithAttribute}" 
    />
```